# Counting one of multiple rows with same value for same ID

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
count( case when EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   business_log bl, subject su
        WHERE  su.ID_SUBJECT = s.ID_SUBJECT
        AND    bl.id_subject = su.id_subject
        AND    bl.value = 'Solved'
        )
then 1 else null end) num_solved
FROM subject s
```

It is posible that one subject is more than once 'Solved' in table BUSINESS_LOG
I want to count only one row solved for one subject.
I must to use only SUBJECT table in the main query because of other counts.

Comment: If you show an example of the data and expected output it would be easier to follow. An exist inside the count doesn't make sense to me..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> business_log:

```
id_business_log id_subject value 
1 1 Solved 
2 2 Evidented 
3 3 Evidented 
4 1 Solved
```

> subject

```
ID_SUBJECT
1
2
3
```

**query with COUNT without CASE**

```
SELECT
ID_SUBJECT,
(
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM   business_log bl
    WHERE  bl.id_subject = s.id_subject
    AND    bl.value = 'Solved'
) as num_solved
FROM subject s
```

returns

```
ID_SUBJECT  num_solved
1   2
2   0
3   0
```

**original query with CASE, but without COUNT**

```
SELECT
ID_SUBJECT,
case when EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   business_log bl
            WHERE  bl.id_subject = s.id_subject
            AND    bl.value = 'Solved'
        )
then 1 else null end num_solved
FROM subject s
```

returns

```
ID_SUBJECT  num_solved
1   1
2   NULL
3   NULL
```

Comment: I've got rows for each subject one, and number 1 in one row that probably represents one solved subject that exists in the database for my query. Thanks, but I'd like only number 1 that represents number of solved subjects - each counted only once even if it is written more than once in the table business_log.

Comment: @StefanDramlic, does you orginal work, if you remove COUNT aggregate function? without COUNT, CASE will return 1 (if solved) or null (if not solved or not exists)

Comment: It doesn't return anything. It has only FROM subject table in the main query because other counts in the same query must count everything from subject table even it doesn't exist in business_log table.

Comment: @StefanDramlic, can you please update your question with small example of existing data and expected output? without them i don't fully understand your question

Comment: I have in table business_log:

id_business_log      id_subject     value

1                           1                  Solved
2                           2                  Evidented
3                           3                  Evidented
4                           1                  Solved


I need result of solved to be 1.

Without using DISTINCT or (+)

Oracle SQL